# TextBox error with large string inside Updatepanel

Tags: textbox, updatepanel

I am getting an error when trying to load more then 2000 characters in asp:TextBox inside update-panel.

I am loading text-box with simple button click.

But if I try to load for example 50 characters, it  is working just fine.

Basically the text gets loaded but there is a unknown server 500 error which disables any further actions inside updatapanel.

Dont really know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was html code inside textbox, solved with validateRequest="false"